# Symfony Constraint/EqualTo compare to entity property

Tags: symfony

How can I use \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EqualTo to compare two different properties of an entity to check if they're equal?

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Did it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Expression validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) to check if two different properties of an entity are equal:

```
// src/AppBundle/Model/MyEntity.php
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getFirstProperty() == this.getSecondProperty()",
 *     message="The first and second properties must be equal!"
 * )
 */
class MyEntity
{
    private firstProperty;

    private secondProperty;

    public function getFirstProperty()
    {
        return $this->firstProperty;
    }

    public function getSecondProperty()
    {
        return $this->secondProperty;
    }
}
```

I don't think it's possible with \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EqualTo.

Comment: It's possible: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/EqualTo.html#propertypath

Answer (score 1):

An example for Symfony 6 (actual version for now, so attributes instead of annotations are used). Standard example: compare password and re-password.

```php
// src/Entity/Person.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Person
{
    #[Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath: "repeatPassword")]
    protected string $password;

    protected string $repeatPassword;
}
```

We compare `password` with `repeatPassword` above, so error message is shown for `password`. If you want it to be shown for `repeatPassword` (i.e. `repeatPassword` to be compared with `password`, and not vice versa), just move `EqualTo` to `repeatPassword` field and change `propertyPath` appropriately.

You can also use [IdenticalTo](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/IdenticalTo.html) instead of `EqualTo`.

Comment: I'm not using Symfony since a long time, thanks for the updated answer, take my vote up!